# Use Ajax to update data on page which is read from text file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to update data on my webpage using `Ajax`. This data is read using `PHP` script
and I want this `function` to carry out EVERY 5 seconds. For some reason, this is not happening at all.

My JavaScript:

```
<script>
 function refresh(){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementClassName("scroll").innerHTML = this.responseText;
   }
 };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "gm.php?q=" + "<?php echo $mf[0]."-".$mf[1].".txt" ?>", true);
// The PHP variables refer to a specific file
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 setInterval(refresh,5000);
</script>
```

My `gm.php` file:

```
 <?php
  $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
  $mr=fopen($q, "a+");
  $line = fgets($mr);
  while (!feof($mr)) {
    $line = $line.fgets($mr);
  } # while ends
  fclose($mr);
  echo $line. "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsClassName` ***NOT*** `document.getElementClassName`

Comment: check about url parameter quotes

Comment: I corrected it to `document.getElementsByClassName("scroll")`, still no help

Comment: Please, open the console in your browser to read the errors then you can fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/642/debugging/10108/using-the-console

Comment: The function runs every 5 seconds, that is not the problem. You have some errors inside your refresh function. Look into your browser console in order to test that. It could be something like CORS errors or passing invalid parameters

Comment: @MohamedAbbas No Help, nothing was shown in `console`.

Comment: What you get when print `this.responseText` in your console.

Comment: @MohamedAbbas Nothing

Comment: @MrigankPawagi then your PHP code return nothing?!

Comment: @MohamedAbbas Yes, Nothing...

Comment: @MrigankPawagi First of all and before dealing with `AJAX` you should test and make sure that your `URL` (php file) returning data as expected. So now, try to open your php file in the browser and check the returned value. if there is no data. then you should debug your php file line by line to determine the problem. after making sure that your php file works as expected then go back to ajax and test it.

Comment: @MohamedAbbas Fine, I will surely try!

Comment: @MohamedAbbas `PHP` is all correct, still, ajax doesn't work...

Comment: @MrigankPawagi Whats the AJAX response ?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas Got it Man! Problem was with my `getelements`. I switched to jQuery and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my element selector was wrong as I was using `get ElementClassName` instead of `getElementsByClassName`. Also, I hadn't given the element index in the class, due to which the element could not be selected.

Another reason was my usage of quotes within the JavaScript string which included the PHP script.

My JavaScript:

```
<script>
 function refresh(){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementsByClassName("scroll")[1].innerHTML = this.responseText;
   }
 };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "gm.php?q=" + '<?php echo $mf[0]."-".$mf[1].".txt" ?>',  true);
// The PHP variables refer to a specific file
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 setInterval(refresh,5000);
</script>
```

My `gm.php` file:

```
 <?php
  $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
  $mr=fopen($q, "a+");
  $line = fgets($mr);
  while (!feof($mr)) {
    $line = $line.fgets($mr);
  } # while ends
  fclose($mr);
  echo $line. "<br />";
?>
```